# Math Proof Question similar to reverse triangle inequality

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that for any real three numbers x,y,z,

$$  |x-y||z| \le |y-z||x| + |z-x||y|$$

I am way overthinking this, there must be an easier solution to this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use $\lvert a\rvert\cdot \lvert b\rvert = \lvert a\cdot b\rvert$. It becomes the ordinary triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice

$$ |x-y||z| = |(x-y)z| = |xz-yz| \leq |xz - yx + yx - yz| \leq |xz-yx| +|yx -yz| = |(z-y)x| + |y(x-z)| = |y-z||x| + |y||x-z|$$

Comment: Thank you, that made it much clearer for me. And that was the same line of thinking that I was on as well!