# $|\alpha-\beta| |\gamma|\leq |\alpha-\gamma| |\beta|+|\gamma-\beta| |\alpha|$

Tags: linear-algebra

$|\alpha-\beta| |\gamma|\leq |\alpha-\gamma| |\beta|+|\gamma-\beta| |\alpha|$ for any vectors $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in Eucildean space $V$.

How to prove it? When does the equal sign holds? What is the geometric meaning?

If one of the three vectors are $0$, then it is OK.

Otherwise, divide both sides by $|\alpha| |\beta| |\gamma|$. But I still could not get something.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/435176/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2368815/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/663964/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7C%5Calpha-%5Cbeta%7C%20%7C%5Cgamma%7C%5Cleq%20%7C%5Calpha-%5Cgamma%7C%20%7C%5Cbeta%7C%2B%7C%5Cgamma-%5Cbeta%7C%20%7C%5Calpha%7C%24)